# Did the edits to this question improve it enough to make it a good, on-topic question?

Tags: discussion, editing

I edited a recently-posted question:  [What are the metrics that can be analysed or derived from a Gantt Chart?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/what-are-the-metrics-that-can-be-analysed-or-derived-from-a-gantt-chart)

I didn't think it needed to be closed because, as a developer/PM, I could relate to the question and saw a way to possibly edit it into shape. I thought about what I would want to know if I were a developer building software for project managers.

This is a prime example of a question that just needed a little grooming to uncover something really awesome.

Is there anything else I could have done to improve the post further? Did my edits actually improve the post enough to keep it open? As a member of the PMSE community, is there anything you learned from looking at the [revision history](https://pm.stackexchange.com/posts/6380/revisions) that you think could help make you a better editor, or help others get over the fear of editing?

Having a solid core group of community editors is an important part of moving towards site graduation, so I'm hoping we can use my edits as an example of what others could do (or maybe not do) based on what happened here.  Let me know what you think! :)

Comment: Still not sure the question is there yet.